# After being drawn into a gate during an Encounter, do you have an Other World encounter in the same turn?

Tags: arkham-horror

The encounter phase is split into two, 1st the locations, then the otherworlds. So you do all the locations, then after that you do all the otherworlds.

So, if you are drawn through the a gate in the Arkham Encounter phase, do you also draw a 2nd otherworld encounter card?

Comment: How embarrasing - the duplicate question is one that I asked a while ago

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

Arkham Horror [rules](http://new.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/Support/Arkham_Horror_Rules_Lo-Res.pdf) (page 10) says your character gets delayed after being sucked be a gate. Beign delayed means that in the next turn, during the movement phase, the only thing you do is to stand your character token (page 16). Nothing else is affected, so you should have your other world encounter.

---

For reference, below is the **wrong** answer I wrote before @Jefromi commented it.

---

No, although I'm unaware of any specific ruling about this.

Arkham Horror [rules](http://new.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/Support/Arkham_Horror_Rules_Lo-Res.pdf) (page 10) says your character gets delayed after being sucked be a gate. Beign delayed means that in the next turn, during the movement phase, the only thing you do is to stand you character token (page 16). Nothing else is affected, so you should have your other world encounter.

But the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AHfaq.pdf) (page 4) says:

> Q: Why is an investigator delayed when a gate opens up in their
>   location, but not delayed if he enters the gate normally?
>
> A: If the investigator was not delayed by a gate opening up in his
>   location, he would be able to get through the Other World having only
>   one Other World Encounter rather than two.

So it seems that an investigators sucked through a gate should have exactly two Other World encounters. Should you have an Other World encounter this turn, next turn you'd stand your character marker, have an encounter in the first Other World position, then in the following turn you'd move to the second position to have a third encounter. This seems to contradict what is suggested in the FAQ. In this situation, the only thing that you can do to avoid violating more specific rules is to not have an Other World encounter when you're sucked by a portal during an encounter.

Comment: So, according to the rules, you are delayed *and* you should have an otherworldly encounter. There's a FAQ which says "you're delayed so that you'll have two instead of one". You've taken this to mean when you would have three, you're still delayed but arbitrarily skip one of them, but you could just as easily take it to mean that you *aren't* delayed if you get drawn through during Arkham encounters. (The much more common case is being drawn through during mythos, when being delayed indeed does cause you to have two instead of one.)

Comment: In any case, based on what's actually in the rules, you definitely have three encounters. Anything else (skipping an encounter or skipping being delayed) seems to definitely be house rules.

Comment: @Jefromi, you're right indeed! Clearly the FAQ isn't specific about the encounters phase. I'll fix the answer.